# ordenar com AngualrJS / orderBy por um campo que será criado posteriormente

Tags: angularjs, ionic, classificação

Estou usando Ionic 1 com angularJs.

Preciso ordenar um resultado por um campo que deve ser criado  posteriormente, o campo é a distancia do primeiro endereço da empresa, no orderBy não sei o que colocar, e também o objeto não está sendo gerado corretamente.

Ou algo que reordene a lista logo apos a geração da mesma.

Obs. Eu não quero ordenar os endereços dentro da empresa, quero ordenar as empresas levando em consideração somente a distancia do primeiro endereço de cada empresa. Essa distancia vai ser calculada com os dados pegues do GPS do usuário.

Fiz um JsFiddle que mostra a situação

https://jsfiddle.net/6dg105q8/1/

Comment: O seu problema está no orderBy, não há como ele ordernar por que você está passando um valor inválido, para o campo distancia funcionar, deve ser no ngRepeat de endereços. https://jsfiddle.net/6dg105q8/3/

Comment: pois é, esse é o problema, eu não quero ordenar os endereços dentro da empresa, quero ordenar as empresas levando em consideração somente a distancia do primeiro endereço de cada empresa.

Comment: Acho que resolvi seu problema, da uma olhada. https://jsfiddle.net/6dg105q8/4/

Comment: Rapaz, é isso ai mesmo, o ng-init deu certo,  posta como solução para eu te dar os pontos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução para o seu problema.

Além de colocar o `ng-init` coloquei uma variável chamada `$scope.predicate` com o campo que você deseja filtrar. Por se tratar de um campo aninhado, ou seja, filho dos elementos do array, precisa definir em uma variável para que a framework consiga interpretar na view.

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.parceiros = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'Empresa 1',
      enderecos: [
        {
          rua: 'dos bobos',
          numero: '0',
          lat: '-3.000000',
          long: '-3.000000'
        },
        {
          rua: 'dos bobos',
          numero: '230',
          lat: '-3.500000',
          long: '-3.500000'
        }
      ]
    },
        {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'Empresa 2',
      enderecos: [
        {
          rua: 'dos bobos',
          numero: '120',
          lat: '-3.700000',
          long: '-3.700000'
        },
        {
          rua: 'dos bobos',
          numero: '121',
          lat: '-3.200000',
          long: '-3.200000'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.predicate = 'enderecos[0].distancia';
    
  $scope.distancia = function(lat1, long1, userLat, userLong) {
   
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
Quando a distancia do primeiro endereço da empresa 2 for menor que o primeiro endereço da empresa 1, a order tem que ser trocada. <br>
Obs. Vai dando RUN para ver que nada muda, a distancia é um random, somente para o exemplo.
<br>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-repeat="parceiro in parceiros | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
      {{parceiro.nome}}
      <div ng-repeat="endereco in parceiro.enderecos | orderBy: '+distancia'" ng-init="endereco.distancia = distancia(lat, long, 0, 0)">
        -- Rua: {{endereco.rua}} - Numero: {{endereco.numero}} - distância: {{endereco.distancia}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Aqui é só para mostrar que o campo foi criado dentro do objeto.</p>
  
  {{parceiros}}
</div>
```